# var d = new Date (); need the days monday to friday

Tags: javascript, getdate

I need to add the days Monday do Friday to a service button, so the button should be shown from Monday to Friday from 9:00 - 12:00 and Monday to Friday from 13:00 to 16:00
Can somebody help me please :-) Thanks a lot!!

```
var d = new Date();
if(d.getHours() >= 9 && d.getHours() <= 12 || d.getHours() >= 13 && d.getHours() <= 16){
    $(".servicebutton").show();
}
else {  
    $(".servicebutton").hide();
}
```

Comment: Put the conditions on either side of the OR into parentheses. `if((d.getHours() >= 9 && d.getHours() <= 12) || (d.getHours() >= 13 && d.getHours() <= 16))`

Comment: Take a look at `getDay` to get the day of week

Comment: thanks! but Can you give me an example of how I get the days Monday to Friday? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
let d = new Date();
let isCorrectHour = (d.getHours() >= 9 && d.getHours() <= 12) || (d.getHours() >= 13 && d.getHours() <= 16);
let isCorrectDay = d.getDay() >= 1 && d.getDay() <= 5; 

if(isCorrectHour && isCorrectDay) $(".servicebutton").show();
else $(".servicebutton").hide();
```

`isCorrectHour` is the condition on hours (from 9:00 - 12:00 or from 13:00 to 16:00).

`isCorrectDay` is the condition on days (from Monday (1) to Friday (5)).

Comment: d.getDay() > 0 && d.getDay() < 6

Comment: @JsonKody `d.getDay() > 0 && d.getDay() < 6` it's the same of `d.getDay() >= 1 && d.getDay() <= 5` don't you think so?

Comment: let day = d.getDay()
let isCorrectDay = 0 < day && day < 6

Comment: well .. I think that most of the time counting from zero is stupid and using '<' instead of '<=' is one of the reasons we count from zero today :/
Counting from zero and using '<=' when unnecessary .. thats really dark humor xD

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
var d = new Date();

var dayIndex = d.getDay(); // sunday = 0, monday = 1 ......

if(((d.getHours() >= 9 && d.getHours() <= 12) || (d.getHours() >= 13 && d.getHours() <= 16)) && (dayIndex > 0 && dayIndex < 6)){
    $(".servicebutton").show();
}
else {  
    $(".servicebutton").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
var d = new Date();
let dateArray = [1,2,3,4,5]; // Days of the week you want it active
if (if dateArray.indexOf(d.getDay()) >=0){
    if(d.getHours() >= 9 && d.getHours() <= 12 || d.getHours() >= 13 && d.getHours() <= 16){
        $(".servicebutton").show();
    }
    else {  
        $(".servicebutton").hide();
    }
} else {
    $(".servicebutton").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Like this

### .getDay()

returns number 0-6 (sunday-saturday)

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".servicebutton")
const date = new Date()
const hour = date.getHours()
const day = date.getDay()

if(day == 0 || day == 6) {
  console.log("Day is saturday or sunday")
} else {

  if( (hour >= 9 && hour <= 12) || (hour >= 13 && hour <= 16) ) {
    button.show();
  }
  else {  
    button.hide();
  }
  
}
```